# Display progress bar in flipview while loading next image in windows 10 apps c#

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-10, windows-8.1-universal

I Used this code to display images in flipview

XAML Code:

```
<Grid>    
  <FlipView x:Name="flpvwImageBind" 
            Margin="0,0,0,0" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            Loading="flpvwImageBind_Loading" 
            Loaded="flpvwImageBind_Loaded">
    <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Image Source="{Binding Thumbnail}" 
               Stretch="Fill" 
               x:Name="image" 
               Margin="0,0,0,0" >
        </Image>
      </DataTemplate>
    </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
  </FlipView>
</Grid>
```

XAML.cs Code

```
flpvwImageBind.ItemsSource = ShowCastManager.Loadpopupimages(PersonID);
```

Here i am binding Images Urls which are from online, so for loading next image it takes time so i want to display progress bar before loading next image, how to do this..

Answer (score 1):

Place the progress ring after the flipview and add Loaded and Loading Events for image Control

```
<Grid>    
<FlipView x:Name="flpvwImageBind" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Loading="flpvwImageBind_Loading" Loaded="flpvwImageBind_Loaded">
            <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Thumbnail}" Loading="image_Loading" Loaded="image_Loaded" Stretch="Fill" x:Name="image" Margin="0,0,0,0" ></Image>
                </DataTemplate>
            </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        </FlipView>
  <ProgressRing x:Name="progressring" Height="50" Width="50"/>
</Grid>
```

and put this code in your cs file

```
private void image_Loading(FrameworkElement sender, object args)
{ 
  progressring.IsActive = true;
}

private void image_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  progressring.IsActive = false;
}
```